# Get frame rate of AVI using AVFoundation

Tags: macos, avfoundation

How can I get the approximate frame rate of an AVI video using AVFoundation ?

Getting `nominalFrameRate` from an `AVAssetTrack` gives a result of 0.0 but the same code works fine on any mov file I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, AVI files don't really work with AV Foundation. QuickTime may be the answer, however.

Comment: It does appear that the current public API for AVFoundation doesn't work well with AVI files.